# WSO2 Identity Server User activation url through email

Tags: passwords, wso2, user-accounts, email-verification, wso2-identity-server

I need to implement email verification for newly registered user accounts in WSO2 Identity Server but I could not find such functionality yet. Is there any feature in the repository that might help me?

Comment: You could use the wso2 ESB for sending emails if you use the user management service through the ESB server. I don't know for verification. Would be useful to know if Identity server has his own email verification service as well though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not yet supported by the WSO2 Identity Server, but will be supported by the new release which is coming soon. Sadly there is no documentation on this yet to give you as a reference. Will update this as soon as a doc is created.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following [link](https://docs.wso2.org/display/IS460/Self+Sign+Up+and+Account+Confirmation) in order to achieve what you want.